# Selectbox disabled or enabled by an option of an other selectbox

Tags: javascript, html, select

I try to create a relation/connexion beetwen 2 selectbox

```
<form id="creation" name="creation">
<select name="select01" id="select01">
     <option value="01">01</option>
     <option value="02">02</option>
     <option value="03">03</option>
</select>

<select name="select02" id="select02">
     <option value="aa">aa</option>
     <option value="bb">bb</option>
     <option value="cc">cc</option>
</select>
</form>
```

I want that my selectbox **select02** be disabled at the begening, and when i click on  **value02** or **value03**, we enable it, and when we click on **value01**, disable it.

There is my code js for the moment. I try to adapt it from an other function (radiobutton enabling a selectbox) but it doesn't seem to work. My list is disable at the beging, but the onclick is not working ...

Some body can help me?

```
var oui = document.creation.select01[0];

document.getElementById("select02").disabled=true;
oui.onclick = function() {
document.getElementById("select02").disabled=false;
}
```

Ok, so NOW, i'm with this code:

```
<script>
var oui = document.select01;
document.getElementById("select02" ).disabled=true;
oui.onchange = function(){
document.getElementById("select02" ).disabled=false;
}
</script>
```

I change the value of my selec01, then my select02 is now enable .. but how can I target only 2 options of my select01 ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form id="creation" name="creation" onchange="handleSelect()">
<select name="select01" id="select01">
     <option value="01">01</option>
     <option value="02">02</option>
     <option value="03">03</option>
</select>

<select name="select02" id="select02" disabled>
     <option value="aa">aa</option>
     <option value="bb">bb</option>
     <option value="cc">cc</option>
</select>
</form>
```

And as a JS script:

```
 function handleSelect() {
     if (this.value == '01') {
         document.getElementById('select02').disabled = true;
     } else {
         document.getElementById('select02').disabled = false;
     }
 }
```

And a tip: explore jQuery, a very popular JS framework (jquery.com). You can achieve your task very simply by using it.

Comment: Wouldnt it be better to put the onchange in the select tag? Otherwise you might disable select02 if you add another selectionbox which also contains value '01'.

Comment: Shouldn't `this.value` be replaced by `document.getElementById('select01').options[document.getElementById('select01').selectedIndex].value` (or a simpler equivalent) ?  Doesn't seem to work otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

```
​document.getElementById('select01').onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById("select02").disabled = this.value == '01';
}​​​​​​​​
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PK2vc/

Answer (score 1):

You must use `onchange` instead of `onclick`. So below should be

```
oui.onclick = function()
```

Replaced with

```
oui.onchange = function()
```

Good Luck !!

Comment: Now i'm using onchange, I change the value of my selec01, then my select02 is now enable .. but how can I target only 2 options of my select01 ?

Comment: @Peter do you mean to say that the action would be perform in particular option select case?

Comment: Yes, but its ok, i verify it like this :if(document.getElementById("typeevent" ).value=='T' || document.getElementById("typeevent" ).value=='G'){

Comment: Its solved, I will post my answer later in 8hours .. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
function handleSelect() {
  if (this.value == '01') {
     document.getElementById('select02').disabled = true;
  } else {
     document.getElementById('select02').disabled = false;
  }
}
```