# Select box enabled through Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to enable a select box when an option is selected in another select box. In this case, when a user selects R or C in the first select box, the second box should be enabled. I have attempted to replicate the solution here: [Selectbox disabled or enabled by an option of an other selectbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269470/selectbox-disabled-or-enabled-by-an-option-of-an-other-selectbox), however the form I am using is set up for submit and rest buttons, as well as many other input and select fields. I am also very new to Javascript and HTML so if there is something silly that I have done, I won't be entirely surprised.

My Javascript function is the following, which is placed after the HTML body code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("part").onchange = function () 
    {       
        if (document.getElementById("part").value == "R" || document.getElementById("part").value == "C") 
        {
            document.getElementByID('part_number').disabled = false;
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementByID('part_number').disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

And the select boxes are:

```
<select class="form-control" name="part[]" id="part" style="display: inline-block; width: 50%;" data-index="1">
    <option value disabled selected> -- Select a part -- </option>
    <option value='R'>R</option>
    <option value='C'>C</option>
</select>
<select multiple class="form-control" name="part_number[]" id="part_number" style="display: inline-block; width: 50%;" disabled>
    <option value disabled selected> -- Select a part -- </option>
    <?php for ($i = 1; $i < 100; $i++){?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

The second box holds the options 1-99 and is disabled by default. The two text boxes can be replicated many times through a dynamic Javascript function which is why I am using arrays. There are no errors in the console of my browser either. I am using the latest version of Google Chrome. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only issue with your code is that you're using `getElementByID` (with capital D) instead of `getElementById` inside the `if else` instruction

It should read:

```
if (selectedPart === "R" || selectedPart  === "C") 
{
    document.getElementById('part_number').disabled = false;
} else {   
    document.getElementById('part_number').disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Unbelievable... haha. Thank you. Please see my comment on the other answer.

Comment: Happens to the best.
I make Paddy's words my own ... not sure what you mean with that new request ... can you rephrase?

Comment: Haha typical coding problems with Notepad++, as brilliant as it is. Ok so when an option is selected within either select box (they are within the same div), the div containing the two is replicated below the original div. This can continue infinitely. When the first select box option is selected then the second one is enabled, the two are replicated, but then the replicated second box is enabled. This should not happen. I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: well ... we would need more code to try to answer to that (and I'm guessing that would be a PHP related question). You didn't provide any code regarding the instructions applied to a wrapper element (not even the wrapper itself). If something like what you described is happening, it has nothing to do with the provided snippets.

Comment: The issue is that the code I am using the replicate everything within the div (wrapper?) was given to me for this purpose and I am not sure if I can share it. The wrapper the selects are contained in is just of a specific class type to the Javascript function. I assume that the problem could be solved using the data-index (in the first select box) which changes with every replication. PHP logic there would then suffice. I can try play around with this though. Thank you @henser.

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting the selected value of the dropdown list correctly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("part").onchange = function () 
    {       
        var partList = document.getElementById("part");
        var selectedPart = partList.options[partList.selectedIndex].value;

        if (selectedPart === "R" || selectedPart  === "C") 
        {
            document.getElementById('part_number').disabled = false;
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById('part_number').disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. With the other answer this works, however, once a value has been selected for one box, every other box is enabled. Is there a way to make the two select boxes a pair?

Comment: @GabrielEisenberg - Not sure what you mean to be honest.  Just corrected the issue in your code - if the logic is not correct, you may need to reword the question.  Also updated to include henser's answer, to fix the inner getElementById.

Comment: The last one was worded horribly which is why I deleted it and added this one. Sorry for that.

Comment: Do you have more than one box with the same ID?

Comment: When they get replicated I assume that they would. That would explain it. A more detailed explanation is in the comments on the other answer.

Comment: @GabrielEisenberg - what you have here is essentially a seperate question and I would recommend you ask it as such.  In general however, having more than one of the same ID is not valid html - you should look at how this is generated.